# Dataset that contains human-written transcripts of videos or audio files

Tags: data-request, nlp

I'm looking for a dataset that contains human-written transcripts of videos or audio files (e.g., podcast). I'm aware of the IWSLT2011 (TED) dataset and [OpenSubtitles](https://github.com/PolyAI-LDN/conversational-datasets/tree/master/opensubtitles). What else exists?